# How to create and use global css variables in jss

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jss, css-in-js

I am sorry for my unclear question. I do not know the keyword so I will try to expland it as clear as possible.
I am using reactjs to build a web project and use jss for UI style. My website use only 4 color, and some element in many component have the same style: for example: my header and my footer have the same button style. I want to create a global class css style for this button, and global color variable. or reuse the color variable name instead of use HEX code.

this is my header style.js file: everyone can see I have 2 the same line: **color: "#02cdce"**, how can I assign an global variable for this HEX code and use its name instead of hex code.
and a global class css to put into the element I want.

```
export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  brand: {
    "&::after": {
      content: '"Khai"',
     **color: "#02cdce",**
      fontWeight: "bold",
    },
  },
  menuItem: {
    "&:hover": {
      **color: "#02cdce",**

      transition: "all 0.4s",
    },
  },
}));
```

Thank for reading my question.

Answer (score 0):

I feel weird posting this but is it as simple as storing the value in a variable?

```
export const globalColors = {
  primaryColor: '#02cdce'
} 

export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  brand: {
    "&::after": {
      content: '"Khai"',
      color: globalColors.primaryColor,
      fontWeight: "bold",
    },
  },
  menuItem: {
    "&:hover": {
      color: globalColors.primaryColor,
      transition: "all 0.4s",
    },
  },
}));
```

Comment: each component has own 1 style.js file. if I use this way I have to create it in every style.js file. My mean is looked like sass structure, create once for every uses

Comment: Ah, well I imagine there are several ways you can do that but I'll update the example with one way to consider: exporting an object from a central js file you use for your styles.